# Azure AD App Service /.auth/refresh endpoint returns 401.71 Unauthorized

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I am testing Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization with Azure AD with a vanilla MVC 5 web app. I have followed the tutorials at https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/ and http://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/

I can confirm that the /.auth/me endpoint functions properly, and that I do have refresh and access tokens in the cache.

The app registration is configured with permission to SharePoint Online.

However, /.auth/refresh fails with 401.71 unauthorized every time. Verbose Log Stream on the Web App only gives a generic error message.

I have seen references to a a value: "access_type=offline" in comment sections on various forums, which may or may not be necessary to include in the "additionalLoginParams" key in authsettings, though it is usually mentioned in the context of Google auth.

Is there a definitive answer on whether this is necessary to add when using AAD? Any other permissions that aren't mentioned in the tutorials?

This is the code I am using to make the test call

```
 string endpoint = myAppUrl + "/.auth/refresh";

 string idToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN"];
 string accessToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN"];
 string refreshToken = this.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-REFRESH-TOKEN"];

 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
 {
     try
     {
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
         HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception oops)
     {
         string oopsMessage = oops.Message;
     }
 }
```

Comment: How are you authenticating with the /.auth/refresh API call?

Comment: I'm calling from c# HttpClient, adding "Bearer" token to DefaultRequestHeaders, the same way I call the /.auth/me, or Graph, etc. I've tried using  the Id, Access, and Refresh tokens. Is it necessary to add Graph permissions?

Comment: I'm also being denied access to the app if I put more than one resource in additionalLoginParams... I can ask another question if that would be more appropriate. Thanks for responding so quickly, btw.

Comment: Interesting. Post the additionalLoginParams as a new question. I have a feeling we don't support that directly, but there are workarounds you can use if your app needs to access multiple resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the /.auth/refresh API does not work with AAD bearer tokens. Instead, you need to either use a session cookie (*AppServiceAuthSession* cookie) or a session token (*x-zumo-auth* header), which are the outputs of a login action.

Sorry about the inconvenience and the lack of clear error information. We'll look into adding support for this in a future release.

Comment: Is this a feature that _should_ continue to function, or is it something that we can expect to go in and out? It's a really good feature and I appreciate all the effort you've put into it.

Comment: Are you asking about the refresh API? You can count on this always being supported - it's super-critical for a lot of apps, especially mobile apps. If anything, we want to make it better.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific. I meant accessing the refresh api directly from a web app, without using a SDK or involving mobile service. There doesn't seem to be much official documentation on AppServiceAuthSession cookies, so I'm keen to know about breaking changes and how stable you considered this method of using them to be.

Comment: Ah, yes, unfortunately we don't really have good protocol documentation at the moment. This is something I'm working on. You should expect that we won't make any breaking changes that would affect any existing apps.

Comment: @ChrisGillum now that it's been more than 3 years to this, wondering if there are any updates on this refresh api, In my case, the initial token is generated for my azure function is by a backend service, there is no way that this api can be used to use cookies. Is there any way for the backend service or for the function app to refresh the token?